# Control 'dgDisplay' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on with Parallel.for

Tags: c#

I get an error trying to use Parallel.For

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnDataGridTextBox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  columnDataGridTextBox.Name = fileDataField[i];
  columnDataGridTextBox.HeaderText = fileDataField[i];
  columnDataGridTextBox.Width = 120;
  dgDisplay.Columns.Add(columnDataGridTextBox);
}
```

my code with paraller.for

```
Parallel.For(0, count, i =>
{
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnDataGridTextBox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  columnDataGridTextBox.Name = fileDataField[i];
  columnDataGridTextBox.HeaderText = fileDataField[i];
  columnDataGridTextBox.Width = 120;
  dgDisplay.Columns.Add(columnDataGridTextBox); <<< this error add colums
});
```

Comment: WinForms or WPF? The reason is that the Parallel.For operation will be running on a thread other than the GUI thread. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx for example. Note you could also create all of the columns in a list and use AddRange at the end out side of the loop, too - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.addrange.aspx

Comment: [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Controls can only be accessed in the thread that created them (and there is only one UI thread). If your call comes from another thread (which it does since you are in a `Parallel.For`) you have to use the `Invoke` method with a delegate to the actual method. To test if you are in the "wrong" thread you can use the `InvokeRequired` property.

```
if (dgDisplay.InvokeRequired)
{
    dgDisplay.Invoke(addColumnDelegate, columnDataGridTextBox);
}
else
{
    dgDisplay.Columns.Add(columnDataGridTextBox);
}
```

When you call this code from inside an event handler of your form it will block because the `Invoke` method will be executed synchronously. You have to use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` to execute it asynchronously.

Apart from that I would not use `Parallel.For` here for two reasons:

1. In a `Parallel.For` you can not predict the order in which the elements will be calculated.
2. Since all calls will end up in the same thread the parallel execution will not give any benefits.

If the column order doesn't matter and you think the creation of Columns should be executed in parallel I would recommend to build an array of `DataGridViewColumn` objects in the `Parallel.For` and then assign them to the control using `dgDisplay.Columns.AddRange(columns)`.